# Disable automatic parameter suggestions in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

How can I disable the suggestion box for method parameters? (I still want to be able to make it show with the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut, if possible)

I write some code, then I type <kbd>,</kbd>. The suggestion box comes up:
[image: a screenshot of parameter hints]

I then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go on the new line, and the suggestion block covers my code:
[image: a screenshot of parameter hints obscuring part of the code after entering a new line]

I tried going through the VSCode settings, but couldn't find the setting for this method parameter suggestion box. I don't know what verbiage is used in the documentation to refer to this box.

Comment: Related, but not the same: [How to get rid of automatic auto complete in VS code](/q/75310821).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called "parameter hints". You can turn off the automatic parameter hint popup by putting this in a settings.json file:

```json
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

That setting's documentation/description says:

> Enables a pop-up that shows parameter documentation and type information as you type.

You can then manually trigger it with the `Trigger Parameter Hints` command, or the corresponding keyboard shortcut:

- Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>
- MacOS: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>